# Setting up broadcasting and multiple-recieve in goroutines

Tags: algorithm, go, concurrency

I'm trying to simulate [Ben-Or's algorithm](https://allquantor.at/blockchainbib/pdf/ben1983another.pdf) in Go, but I can't figure out how to broadcast and receive messages between multiple goroutines.

I've implemented a different goroutine (SimulateOneProc) for each processor, and want to send one message for each processor. Then the processor receives the sent messages from all other processors (including itself) and proceeds.

```golang
func SimulateBenOr(n, t int) {
    processes := initProcesses(n)
    messages := make(chan Message)
    ratifier := make(chan Message)

    for i := range processes {
        go simulateOneProc(n, t, processes[i], messages, ratifier)
    }
    fmt.Scanln()
}

func simulateOneProc(n, t int, process Process, messages chan Message, ratifier chan Message) {
        fmt.Println("starting round", process.round, "for processor", process.id)
        var message1 Message
        message1.pref = process.pref
        message1.round = process.round

        // send this process's preference and round
        go func(message1 Message, messages chan Message) {
            for i := 1; i <= n; i++ {
                fmt.Println("sending message", process.pref, "from processor", process.id)
                messages <- message1
            }
        }(message1, messages)

        // wait for n-t messages
        for i := 1; i <= n; i++ {
            newMessage := <-messages
            fmt.Println("recieved message", newMessage.pref, "by processor", process.id)
            }
}
```

I tried using a single send and n recieves for each processor, but that didn't work. I tried sending and receiving n times but that leads to multiple receives of the same message by a particular processor while some other receive is left empty. What is the best way to do this? I'm a complete beginner to parallel programming, so I'm sorry for any basic mistakes I've made.

Comment: You mean like this? [How to broadcast message using channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417199/how-to-broadcast-message-using-channel/49877632?r=SearchResults#49877632)

Comment: Yes, but maybe where the same struct can both send and receive messages?