# Go PubSub without mutexes?

Tags: go, publish-subscribe

I will be implementing notification system into website backend where each page visit will subscribe user to some data that are displayed on the page and when there are changes in the system, he will be notified about it. For example someone is viewing a page with news articles and when a new article is posted, i want to notify the user so he can then fetch these new articles via js or by reloading the page. Either manually or automatically.

To make this happen I will be using channels in a pub/sub manner. So for example there will be a "news" channel. When new article is created, this channel will receive id of this article. When user opens up a page and subscribes to "news" channel(probably via websocket), there will have to be a list of subscribers for this news channel into which he will be added as a subscriber to be notified.

Something like:

```
type Channel struct {
  ingres <-chan int // news article id
  subs [] chan<- int
  mx sync.Mutex
}
```

There will be goroutine for each of these that will be distributing what comes into ingress into the subs list.

Now the problem I am looking at, probably premature optimization, is that there will be a lot of channels and a lot of coming and going subscribers. Which means there will be a lot of stop-the-world events with mutextes. For example if there are 10 000 users online, subscribed to news channel, the goroutine will have to send 10k notifications WHILE the subs slice will be locked so new subscribers will have to wait for mutex to unlock. And now multiply this by 100 channels and I think we have a problem.

So I am looking for a way to add and remove subscribers without blocking other subscribers from being added or removed or potentially just to receive the notification in acceptable time across the board.

That "waiting for all subs to receive" problem can be solved with goroutine for each sub with timeout so after the id is received, 10k goroutines will be created and mutex can be unlocked right away. But still, it can add up with multiple channels.

Comment: Something like this? [How to broadcast message using channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417199/how-to-broadcast-message-using-channel/49877632#49877632)

Comment: The limitation of channels for pub/sub is that they are all in memory.  If you add an additional server or restart existing service you'll lose the whole thing.  You might want to think about how you can implement pubsub atop a persistent data layer such as redis, rabbitmq, etc.  It will also probably sidestep a number of concurrency concerns like the ones you ask about.

Comment: Your Channel type is similar to the Gorilla chat example Hub type.  The Gorilla Hub does not use mutexes.  See the [readme file](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat#hub) for details.

Comment: Thank you for the links. They both use the same approach. After a bit of thought, I think this is the best solution right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the linked comments I have came up with this code:

```
package notif

import (
    "context"
    "sync"
    "time"
    "unsafe"
)

type Client struct {
    recv   chan interface{}
    ch     *Channel
    o      sync.Once
    ctx    context.Context
    cancel context.CancelFunc
}

// will be nil if this client is write-only
func (c *Client) Listen() <-chan interface{} {
    return c.recv
}

func (c *Client) Close() {
    select {
    case <-c.ctx.Done():
    case c.ch.unsubscribe <- c:
    }
}

func (c *Client) Done() <-chan struct{} {
    return c.ctx.Done()
}

func (c *Client) doClose() {
    c.o.Do(func() {
        c.cancel()
        if c.recv != nil {
            close(c.recv)
        }
    })
}

func (c *Client) send(msg interface{}) {
    // write-only clients will not handle any messages
    if c.recv == nil {
        return
    }
    t := time.NewTimer(c.ch.sc)
    select {
    case <-c.ctx.Done():
    case c.recv <- msg:
    case <-t.C:
        // time out/slow consumer, close the connection
        c.Close()
    }
}

func (c *Client) Broadcast(payload interface{}) bool {
    select {
    case <-c.ctx.Done():
        return false
    default:
        c.ch.Broadcast() <- &envelope{Message: payload, Sender: uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(c))}
        return true
    }
}

type envelope struct {
    Message interface{}
    Sender  uintptr
}

// leech is channel-blocking so goroutine should be called internally to make it non-blocking
// this is to ensure proper order of leeched messages.
func NewChannel(ctx context.Context, name string, slowConsumer time.Duration, emptyCh chan string, leech func(interface{})) *Channel {
    return &Channel{
        name:        name,
        ingres:      make(chan interface{}, 1000),
        subscribe:   make(chan *Client, 1000),
        unsubscribe: make(chan *Client, 1000),
        aud:         make(map[*Client]struct{}, 1000),
        ctx:         ctx,
        sc:          slowConsumer,
        empty:       emptyCh,
        leech:       leech,
    }
}

type Channel struct {
    name        string
    ingres      chan interface{}
    subscribe   chan *Client
    unsubscribe chan *Client
    aud         map[*Client]struct{}
    ctx         context.Context
    sc          time.Duration
    empty       chan string
    leech       func(interface{})
}

func (ch *Channel) Id() string {
    return ch.name
}

// subscription is read-write by default. by providing "writeOnly=true", it can be switched into write-only mode
// in which case the client will not be disconnected for being slow reader.
func (ch *Channel) Subscribe(writeOnly ...bool) *Client {
    c := &Client{
        ch: ch,
    }
    if len(writeOnly) == 0 || writeOnly[0] == false {
        c.recv = make(chan interface{})
    }
    c.ctx, c.cancel = context.WithCancel(ch.ctx)
    ch.subscribe <- c
    return c
}

func (ch *Channel) Broadcast() chan<- interface{} {
    return ch.ingres
}

// returns once context is cancelled
func (ch *Channel) Start() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-ch.ctx.Done():
            for cl := range ch.aud {
                delete(ch.aud, cl)
                cl.doClose()
            }
            return
        case cl := <-ch.subscribe:
            ch.aud[cl] = struct{}{}

        case cl := <-ch.unsubscribe:
            delete(ch.aud, cl)
            cl.doClose()
            if len(ch.aud) == 0 {
                ch.signalEmpty()
            }

        case msg := <-ch.ingres:
            e, ok := msg.(*envelope)
            if ok {
                msg = e.Message
            }
            for cl := range ch.aud {
                if ok == false || uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(cl)) != e.Sender {
                    go cl.send(e.Message)
                }
            }
            if ch.leech != nil {
                ch.leech(msg)
            }
        }
    }
}

func (ch *Channel) signalEmpty() {
    if ch.empty == nil {
        return
    }

    select {
    case ch.empty <- ch.name:
    default:
    }
}

type subscribeRequest struct {
    name string
    recv chan *Client
    wo   bool
}

type broadcastRequest struct {
    name string
    recv chan *Channel
}

type brokeredChannel struct {
    ch     *Channel
    cancel context.CancelFunc
}

type brokerLeech interface {
    Match(string) func(interface{})
}

func NewBroker(ctx context.Context, slowConsumer time.Duration, leech brokerLeech) *Broker {
    return &Broker{
        chans:     make(map[string]*brokeredChannel, 100),
        subscribe: make(chan *subscribeRequest, 10),
        broadcast: make(chan *broadcastRequest, 10),
        ctx:       ctx,
        sc:        slowConsumer,
        empty:     make(chan string, 10),
        leech:     leech,
    }
}

type Broker struct {
    chans     map[string]*brokeredChannel
    subscribe chan *subscribeRequest
    broadcast chan *broadcastRequest
    ctx       context.Context
    sc        time.Duration
    empty     chan string
    leech     brokerLeech
}

// returns once context is cancelled
func (b *Broker) Start() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-b.ctx.Done():
            return
        case req := <-b.subscribe:
            ch, ok := b.chans[req.name]
            if ok == false {
                ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(b.ctx)
                var l func(interface{})
                if b.leech != nil {
                    l = b.leech.Match(req.name)
                }
                ch = &brokeredChannel{
                    ch:     NewChannel(ctx, req.name, b.sc, b.empty, l),
                    cancel: cancel,
                }
                b.chans[req.name] = ch
                go ch.ch.Start()
            }
            req.recv <- ch.ch.Subscribe(req.wo)

        case req := <-b.broadcast:
            ch, ok := b.chans[req.name]
            if ok == false {
                ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(b.ctx)
                var l func(interface{})
                if b.leech != nil {
                    l = b.leech.Match(req.name)
                }
                ch = &brokeredChannel{
                    ch:     NewChannel(ctx, req.name, b.sc, b.empty, l),
                    cancel: cancel,
                }
                b.chans[req.name] = ch
                go ch.ch.Start()
            }
            req.recv <- ch.ch

        case name := <-b.empty:
            if ch, ok := b.chans[name]; ok {
                ch.cancel()
                delete(b.chans, name)
            }
        }
    }
}

// subscription is read-write by default. by providing "writeOnly=true", it can be switched into write-only mode
// in which case the client will not be disconnected for being slow reader.
func (b *Broker) Subscribe(name string, writeOnly ...bool) *Client {
    req := &subscribeRequest{
        name: name,
        recv: make(chan *Client),
        wo:   len(writeOnly) > 0 && writeOnly[0] == true,
    }
    b.subscribe <- req
    c := <-req.recv
    close(req.recv)
    return c
}

func (b *Broker) Broadcast(name string) chan<- interface{} {
    req := &broadcastRequest{name: name, recv: make(chan *Channel)}
    b.broadcast <- req
    ch := <-req.recv
    close(req.recv)
    return ch.ingres
}
```